# Unable to access css global variables from within Ion-Content

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, css-selectors, ionic5

I may be missing some understanding of how Ion-Content component works, but I am unable to access css global variables from within children of my Ion-Content component. Whenever I try assign a global variable for a css property, it tells me that the global variable is not defined
[global variable not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJvX.png)

In all other elements outside of the ion-content, when inspecting their css, I can see that they inherit from #document where the global css variables are defined, however, when I inspect any child of , it does not inherit these global variables and so I am unable to reference them.
[Other elements inheriting global variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM9kj.png)

Is there some property about  that stops global variables bheing passed down? And is there any way that I can access them from the css of ion-content's children?

I have tried creating new global variables within Ion-content to pass down the variables, and using sass variables, all of which just reference back to the global variable, which is undefined inside of .

I expect css global variables to be accessible from within children of  just like they are anywhere else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto the same situation where my variables were not visible inside Ion-Content and the inspect stated that they were 'undefined', but they were still working. I know it's not a fix but I spent some time looking for an answer as well until I realized it was a false issue and everything was working as expected.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35064188)